# How does raising the Russian interest rate defend the Ruble from devaluation?

Tags: interest-rate, currency, international-economics, government, foreign-exchange

Raising interest rates to minimize currency devaluation is being adopted in countries like Brazil and Russia:

- [Brazilian interest rate](https://www.tradingeconomics.com/brazil/interest-rate)
  [image: Brazilian interest rate]
- [Russian interest rate](https://www.tradingeconomics.com/russia/interest-rate)
  [image: Russian interest rate]

How does raising the interest rate protect the value of a currency?

I am used to seeing news about governments raising interest rates with the aim of protecting their currency. However, I never saw an explanation on how these two things are related.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the question and giving more explanation than just the links?

Comment: Hello @Soccerman, I accept suggestions / reviews. Despite I understand well English language, I'm still learning grammar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interest rate is the return that a lender earns on money lent to someone else. If the interest rate is higher then it makes lending money more attractive because the return is higher.

In particular, if the interest rate in, say, Russia increases relative to that in the USA then American lenders will switch from lending their money in America to lending their money in Russia where the return is greater. But in order to lend money in Russia, these investors are first going to have to convert their dollars into roubles. This increased demand for roubles causes the price of the rouble (i.e. the exchange rate) to increase.

Answer (score 0):

According to uncovered interest parity model, if you raise the domestic currency's bank deposit interest rate, then, ceteris paribus, the currency will appreciate. This can be shown mathematically.

Comment: Why not adding some parts of that mathematical explanation? That would greatly improve your answer.